# Printing Image from Document Library

Tags: picture-library, printing, picture

I am attempting to print an image from a picture library. I have tried the following methods:

1. click the thumbnail to display the full image in the browser.  Use the browser print function. This method does not shrink the image to fit on a single page even though it has that option available in the menu for scaling size.
2. Using the Name menu, choosing Edit Document.  I get an error stating no compatible software is installed.  Yet, when I right-click on a .jpg file located on my desktop and choose Edit, the Microsoft Office Picture Manager software opens.

I would prefer to use option 2 as it would also give us the ability to edit the image as well as print it properly, but I'll take any method that will print the image on a single page no matter what the native image size actually is.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use option 1 with Firefox as your browser. It has the option to shrink the image so that it fits on one page.